# While loop ending early?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

```
first_name = input("Please enter your first name: ").capitalize()
start_inner = int(input("Hi {}, please enter the start value for the inner loop: ".format(first_name)))
end_inner = int(input("Please enter the end value for the inner loop: "))
start_outer = int(input("Please enter the start value for the outer loop: "))
end_outer = int(input("Please enter the end value for the outer loop: "))

while start_outer <= end_outer:
        while start_inner <= end_inner:
                print("{:>1} {:>1}".format(start_outer,start_inner))
                start_inner = start_inner +1
        start_outer = start_outer +1
print("After the loop")
```

If i were to enter 1(start_inner), 4(end_inner), 1(start_outer), 3(end_outer)

I should get

```
1 1
1 2
1 3
1 3
2 1
2 2
2 3
2 4
3 1
3 2
3 3
3 4
```

Instead, I get

```
1 1
1 2
1 3
1 4
```

I asked a very similar question about for loops and adding +1 in my print seemed to help but no luck with while loops.

thanks

Comment: You do not reset `start_inner`. Its value only ever increases in the first loop iteration until `start_inner > end_inner`, and then it stays there for the rest of the outer loops. Just go through it with pen and paper and you'll see it.

Comment: Why don't you use `for in` loops with the [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range) class?

Answer (score 0):

Your `start_inner` is not getting reset back to your initial value. Try using an intermediate variable to iterate over or better yet use a `for` loop.

```
start_inner = 1
end_inner = 4
start_outer = 1
end_outer = 3

while start_outer <= end_outer:
    iter_start_inner = start_inner
    while iter_start_inner <= end_inner:
            print("{:>1} {:>1}".format(start_outer,iter_start_inner))
            iter_start_inner += 1
    start_outer = start_outer +1
print("After the loop")
```

`for` loop alternative

```
for i in range(start_outer,end_outer+1):
    for j in range(start_inner,end_inner+1):
            print("{:>1} {:>1}".format(i,j))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset start inner again once after inner loop

```
start_inner = 1
end_inner = 4
start_outer = 1
end_outer = 3    
while start_outer <= end_outer:
            while start_inner <= end_inner:
                    print("{:>1} {:>1}".format(start_outer,start_inner))
                    start_inner = start_inner +1
            start_inner = 1        
            start_outer = start_outer +1
    print("After the loop")
```

Answer (score 0):

OR:

```
...
print('\n'.join("{:>1} {:>1}".format(i,j) for i in range(start_outer,end_outer+1) for j in range(start_inner,end_inner+1)))
print("After the loop")
```